# PHP stopped working on Apache after upgrade to OS x 10.10.1 Yosemite - Owncloud broken

Tags: php, html, apache, osx-yosemite, owncloud

Context: I'm trying to run Apache on my local Mac27" (2009) so that I can use OwnCloud as an alternative to Apple's iCloud (I just want to do local sync of my calendar like in the good-old "OS X big cat" days. For paranoid privacy reasons I don't want Cupertino to know who I know or what I'm doing - probably misplaced, but there you go). My foray into this were based on a blog post by Michael Gracie at http://michaelgracie.com/2013/11/13/getting-ios-7-calendar-and-contacts-syncing-directly-with-os-x-10-9-mavericks/ (for which many thanks are due).

When I upgraded to Yosemite a few weeks ago (remind me why I did this?) I spent an age mending my very simple setup and I was back . Yesterday I upgraded (again, remind me why I did this?) to 10.10.1 and it broke again. Everything seems like it should work, but PHP is not running.

The symptom is that, when I run OwnCloud (localhost/owncloud/index.htm), I get the OwnCloud logo and styling and then an error:

```
PHP module GD is not installed.
Please ask your server administrator to install the module.
```

This, however, is a diversion, because it's not the GD module which is the problem - I think that Apache can't see PHP at all. The reason is as follows:

**1) Does PHP run on Apache?**

When I go to:

```
http://localhost
```

I see the Apache "It Works!" message.

Adapting the index.html.en file in /Library/Webserver/documents/ allows me to modify that message, however, when I call PHP from within that file e.g.

> ```
>     <h1>It works!</h1>
>     <h2>This file is in /Library/Webserver/Documents</h2>
>     <h3>Trying to printout phpinfo()</h3>
>     <?php
>             echo phpinfo();
>     ?>
> ```

Then I see three lines of text but no PHP info.

So PHP is not available when rendering that webpage.

**2) Is PHP available at all?**

Investigating this, I run the following command from the terminal:

```
sudo echo <?php phpinfo() ?> | php
```

and I get four-thousand lines of PHP info, which includes

```
'--with-gd'
```

in the configure command.

**3) Has Apache loaded the PHP module?**

I then run:

```
httpd -t -D DUMP_MODULES
```

Apache tells me that, among many other modules it is using:

```
php5_module (shared)
```

**4) Is the httpd.conf file compatible with this:**

I've been through httpd.conf in my /etc/apache2 directory and have uncommented the following lines:

```
LoadModule php5_module        libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
LoadModule authn_core_module libexec/apache2/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module libexec/apache2/mod_authz_host.so
```

**5) What else?**

Just to complete the picture, in my /etc/apache2/users file I have configured my own user settings to:

```
<Directory "/Users/DJBrown/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

(I confess, at this point - as well as others - I'm really not quite sure what I'm doing since I've following much of this from some other answers in StackOverflow).

**6) Conclusion**

Apache is running with PHP is loaded and both httpd and PHP can be interrogated from the command line ... but Apache won't run PHP.

Is that possible?

What have I missed?

Any help gratefully received.

DJ

Comment: a guess: `*.html.en` is not usually associated with the php-interpreter try a test.php with `phpinfo()`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I did try it out as testphp.html (test.php won't load into Safari).The behaviour remains the same whatever the name of the file

Comment: apache wont execute any php in non *.php files - you should fix that first - `test.php won't load into Safari` is the problem

Comment: Great. That's helpful. Any ideas how I persuade safari to load a php file? I've never before rendered PHP directly in a browser, outside the context of an HTML file.

Comment: Sorry! I'm being an idiot. INFO.PHP file does load in safari via Localhost, not simply by asking the application to render it. (Slaps forehead repeatedly).

Comment: I've worked to a partial solution

Answer (score 1):

Here's a partial answer.

Changing the line in httpd.conf

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

to

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

Permits apache to render in-line PHP code in HTML files.

(I got this from http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/p/html_php.htm)

I still have an OwnCloud problem now, which I will take to their forum

Thanks for your help birdspider

DJ

Comment: Thanks! This line fixed my Apache PHP. I was struggling with this. Installed Homebrew PHP, still not working. Now everything is ok.